# Передать информацию с поля для ввода(html) в пхп код

Tags: php, html

Например, я написал в поле для ввода, сделанного в html и хочу передать эту информацию в php, и он тем самым должен его обработать и вывести информацию в другое поле, как?

Comment: Делаете форму, в эту форму помещаете поле и кнопку submit. В php скрипте принимаете данные через $_POST['имя поля'] или $_GET['имя поля'] и делаете с переменной то, что вам нужно. В интернете полно информации и примеров как работать с формами

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например в html написан input поле :
 тут res может быть что угодно что хотите только не начинать с цифр. Чтобы получить значение input в php пишите такой код ну там нужно ещё аналтзирлвать какая переменная потом но в общем. Пишите $a = $_POST['res']; но input должен быть в form теге и method="post" и все с переменной $a делаете что хотите